# Inverse sampling a direction over the hemisphere of a surface?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, geometry

Let $S^2:=\{x\in\mathbb R^3:|x|=1\}$ denote the unit 2-sphere, $$\omega_{x\to y}:=\frac{y-x}{|y-x|}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in\mathbb R^3\text{ with }x\ne y,$$ $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ be the disjoint union of surfaces (assume spheres, for simplicity) and $$\operatorname{tr}(x,\omega):=\inf\{t>0:x+t\omega\in M\}\;\;\;\text{for }(x,\omega)\in M\times S^2$$ (assume $\tau<\infty$ which is always achievable by adding a sphere surrounding each surface in $M$).

Now let $U:[0,1]^2\to[-1,1]^2$, $u\mapsto 2u-(1,1)$, $$T:[0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi)\to\mathbb R^2\;,\;\;\;(r,\phi)\mapsto r(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$$ denote the transformation from polar to cartesian coordinates and $$C(x,y):=\begin{cases}\displaystyle T\left(x,\frac\pi4\frac yx\right)&\text{, if }x>-y,x>y\\\displaystyle T\left(y,\frac\pi4\left(2-\frac xy\right)\right)&\text{, if }x>-y,x\le y\\\displaystyle T\left(-x,\frac\pi4\left(4+\frac yx\right)\right)&\text{, if }x\le-y,x<y\\\displaystyle T\left(-y,\frac\pi4\left(6-\frac xy\right)\right)&\text{, if }x\le-y,x\ge y\ne 0\\ T(0,0)&\text{, if }x\le-y,x\ge y=0\end{cases}$$ for $(x,y)\in[-1,1]^2$ denote [Shirley’s concentric map](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Monte_Carlo_Integration/2D_Sampling_with_Multidimensional_Transformations.html#SamplingaUnitDisk) mapping the unit square to the unit circle.

Given $x\in M$, $\omega\in S^2$ and $\in[0,1]^2$, I sample $\omega'\in S^2$ in the following way:

- Let $d:=(C\circ U)(u)$ and $z:=\sqrt{1-|d|^2}$.
- Set $\omega':=(d_1,d_2,z)$.
- If $\omega_3>0$, set $\omega'_3=-z$.

Denote this sampling function by $\omega'=f(\omega,u)$.

Now, given $x^{(1)}\in M$, $\omega^{(1)}\in S^2$ and $u^{(2)},\ldots,u^{(k)}\in[0,1]^2$, I sample $x^{(2)},\ldots,x^{(k)}\in M$ and $\omega^{(2)},\ldots,x^{(k)}\in S^2$ with $\omega^{(i+1)}=f\left(\omega^{(i)},u^{(i)}\right)$ and $x^{(i+1)}=\operatorname{tr}\left(x^{(i)},\omega^{(i+1)}\right)$ so that $\omega^{(i+1)}=\omega_{x^{(i)}\to x^{(i+1)}}$.

> What I need now is computing $v^{(1)},\ldots,v^{(k-1)}\in[0,1]^2$ such that $-\omega^{(i)}=f\left(-\omega^{(i+1)},v^{(1)}\right)$. Clearly, $f$ is analytically invertible. However, my implementation of the inversion is suffering from floating-point imprecision (I've asked a corresponding question on https://stackoverflow.com/q/60017703/547231). Instead of $-\omega^{(i)}$ I only obtain an approximation $-\tilde\omega^{(i)}$ and this approximation will not satisfy $$x^{(i)}=\operatorname{tr}\left(x^{(i+1)},-\tilde\omega^{(i)}\right)\tag1$$ (but the correct solution obviously does).

I doubt that I will find a solution which guarantees that $(1)$ holds. However, the only thing I really need to ensure is that $\operatorname{tr}\left(x^{(i+1)},-\tilde\omega^{(i)}\right)$ is "close" to $x^{(i)}$ (most importantly, it should lie on the same surface as $x^{(i)}$ does).

Imagine a "ray" from $x^{(i)}$ to $x^{(i+1)}$ along the direction $\omega^{(i+1)}$. If we perturb $\omega^{(i+1)}$ just a little bit, it might happen that we "hit" an other surface than we would without the perturbation.

The worst thing is that the error seems to propagate. If $\tilde x^{(i)}:=\operatorname{tr}\left(x^{(i+1)},-\tilde\omega^{(i)}\right)$ is not equal to $x^{(i)}$, the next ray starts from the wrong position $\tilde x^{(i)}$ ...

Comment: The mathjax in the first displayed box do not work, but I cannot see any problems ...

Comment: I'm stuck at the outset, because you don't describe a two-sphere: you give a map from $\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \Delta_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ into $S^2 = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid |x|=1\}.$ The problem with mathematical solecisms like this is that we cannot be sure you actually mean anything else you write later in the question, but there's no English description of your statistical problem we can fall back on to understand what you might be trying to say.  Could you provide some of that context?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen It should work now.

Comment: @whuber What do you mean by "you don't describe a 2-sphere"? The 2-sphere is $\{x\in\mathbb R^3:|x|=1\}$.

Comment: That appears nowhere in your post.  Your description is not of a 2-sphere, but of a map $\omega$ whose image is the 2-sphere.  You then go on to refer to that map as if it were an element of $S^2,$ without explaining what arguments it might be applied to.  The whole thing is inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: @whuber I think you've misunderstood the grammar. The first comma in my first sentence should not introduce the definition of $S^2$, but is a separar of the enumeration of definitions I give. Please note that I've updated the whole question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Although I contemplated that interpretation, it didn't (and still does not) make sense, because you are using the symbol "$\omega$" in two distinctly different ways.  Is it a function or is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$? If the latter, what subset is it??

Comment: @whuber Why would you think it is is a subset? The symbol $\omega_{x\to y}$ is defined to be $\frac{y-x}{|y-x|}$. The other $\omega$'s ($\omega^{(i)}$, $\omega$, $\omega'$) are different symbols.

Comment: Then what's the point of defining $\omega_{x\to y}$ in the first place?  Where does it ever reappear?  This is not a definition of $S^2,$ because it depends on two free variables "$x$" and "$y.$"

Comment: If i wouldn't know better, I'd say you're trying to kid me. The first sentence is an enumeration of definitions. I've defined $S^2$ to be $\{x\in\mathbb R^3:|x|=1\}$ and $\omega_{x\to y}$ to be $\frac{y-x}{|y-x|}$ (whenever $x,y\in\mathbb R^3$ with $x\ne y$). Later on, I've described how I sample $\omega^{(n+1)}$ and that I set $x^{(i+1)}=\operatorname{tr}\left(x^{(i)},\omega^{(i+1)}\right)$. Now the definition of $\omega_{x\to y}$ is handy, since it allows us to write $\omega^{(i+1)}=\omega_{x^{(i)}\to x^{(i+1)}}$.